# nested forms and cocoon. undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

Hi all. When I open `/courses/new` (or `/courses/some_id/edit`), browser returns this error:

```
Showing /app/views/dashboard/courses/_price.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass
```

Here are codes, `_form.html.erb`:

```
 <%= simple_form_for [:dashboard, @course], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

//////
<%= f.fields_for :prices do |p|%>
  <%= render 'price', :f => 'prices' %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :prices %>

////////
```

`_price.html.erb`:

```
<%= p.label :price %>
<%= p.text_field :price %>
<%= p.label :desc %>
<%= p.text_field :description %>
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
```

Models:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :prices
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

How resolve this error? And why it has arisen?

Comment: You are using `simple_form_for`,i guess it should be `<%= f.simple_fields_for :prices do |p|%>`

Comment: With my suggestion or with Mr Yoshiji's answer?

Comment: with your suggestion too. Your suggestion resolve main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **`simple_form_for`**,so i guess this line

```
<%= f.fields_for :prices do |p|%>
```

should be

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :prices do |p|%>
```

Have a look at the **[Git](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)** for more Info.

Comment: Helpful, thanks. BTW, Pavan, can you help me resolve one problem with gem 'cocoon'?

Comment: @DmitrySharikov If its a gem issue then i can't because i know nothing about cocoon gem.

Comment: This answer did not solve the question. Your answer does not provide a solution for the `undefined method 'label' for nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 1):

In your `_price.html.erb` partial view, your are using a form builder that does not exists (is `nil`) because you did not pass it as argument:

```
# _price.html.erb
<%= p.label :price %>
   #^ the variable `p` is the form builder here
```

To solve this problem, you have to pass the form builder to the partial view, like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :prices do |p| %>
  <%= render 'price', :f => 'prices', p: p %>
                                     #^^^^ We pass the variable `p` (form builder) to the partial
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: One doubt.Is `fields_for` is allowed to use with `simple_form_for` also?

Comment: I guessed self. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Pavan `simple_form_for` is a extension of the already existing `form_for`. `simple_fields_for` would give more options and use the `simple_form_for` syntax to define new input fields.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I actually didn't know that.But OP said that it is working with my suggestion,so i **`undeleted`** my answer.

Comment: I know I have enough reputation to see the deleted answers. I was just posting this comment in order to tell other people having the same problem that your answer does not solve it